# aria - multiline purpose

Tags: html

I read from this site [Site]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968006.aspx
that aria-multiline is to provide the multi line attribute.

But when i applied to textbox, it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please tell why. I have one more question, can anyone please tell me the difference between these two elements

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="text"></textarea>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" aria-labelledby="aria-text-label" id="aria-text"    role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></textarea>
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't textarea is multiline input field by default? And how it "doesn't seem to work"? What you expected and what you get?

Comment: That's what confused me. Textarea is by default multi lined, then y we need to specify this aria attribute??? If i want to make textbox multi lined, is there any other way ?

Comment: In the second line. Although its text area, its role is set as textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARIA attributes are declarative (informative). They inform browsers and especially assistive software what functional properties elements *have*, mainly due to JavaScript code that processes them, instead of *making* elements have functional properties. For example, if you used JavaScript to make a `div` element a multi-line input area, it would be appropriate to set `aria-multiline="true"` on that element. See the W3C [WAI Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-primer/).

Thus, the attribute is redundant for `textarea` (browsers can be expected to know what that element is). For `input type="text"` it could be used, but only if you have somehow managed to turn it to a multiline control.

The differences between the two elements presented in the question are:

- They assign different `id` attribute values.
- The latter declares a `role` attribute, which matches the default semantics and is not recommended in [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/). (It is allowed, but it may confuse people who read the HTML source and mislead them into thinking that it has some effect.)
- It also redundantly declares the element as multiline.
- It additionally specifies that the element has a label, which is an element with `id="aria-text-label"`. This is not redundant, but it is normally better, more accessible, to have the label declared in normal HTML markup, using the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Answer (score 0):

Have you read `Remarks` part of your link? Since `textarea` is multiline by default, so setting `aria-multiline="true"` will have no efect. This attribute sets what **ENTER** key do. In textarea and when `aria-multiline="true"` it will continue input to second row. But if you set `aria-multiline="false"` for `textarea`, it will act as `<input type="text"/>` - it will submit form on Enter key press and will not jump to second row.